# Как используя instr обрезать строку

Tags: oracle, plsql

Мне нужно обрезать строку типа

```
[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]
```

Мой код:

```
 select substr('[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]',  
           instr('[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]', '[',1,3), 
           instr('[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]', ']',1,3) )                            
      from dual
```

Ожидаемый результат: слово без квадратных скобок    `Camry`
Сейчас второй instr работает не корректно(

Comment: Используйте `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`.

Comment: а у вас формат данных всегда такой?

Comment: @Viktorov, да всегда

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, второй `INSTR` работает корректно.

Проблема в том, что третий аргумент [`SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679) — длина подстроки, а не индекс последнего символа, который возвращает `INSTR`. С учетом этого нужно будет отсчитать длину. Например, так:

```
select substr('[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]',
          instr('[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]', '[', 1, 3) + 1,
          instr('[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]', ']', 1, 3) - instr('[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]', '[', 1, 3)-1)
from dual
```

Но проще для этой цели воспользоваться [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303):

```
select regexp_substr('[TextValue][WINDOM][Camry]', '\[([^]]+)\]', 1, 3, null, 1)
from dual
```